# Runbook can't use command New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

When I'm trying to run the command `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` in an PowerShell Runbook it fails with the error message:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have verified that all modules are updated, `AzureRM.Sql` has version 4.12.1 when I'm writing this. `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` is a part of `AzureRM.Sql` and is also available in the runbook editor.

What I'm missing?

**Update:** The code I'm trying to run looks something like this:

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -ServerName "MyServerName" -DatabaseName "MyDatabaseName" -StorageKeytype StorageAccessKey -StorageKey "MyStorageKey" -StorageUri "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/backupdb/db.bacpac" -AdministratorLogin "userName" -AdministratorLoginPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

It does work Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Check all your parameters are the correct values you are expecting and match what New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport expects.

Comment: You're right, I should have provided an example. The question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the command is executed, make sure that you are authenticated. Adding these lines before the command will solve this problem:

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
-ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint
```

You find more information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell